# Keep a CSS property until the transition of the other ends

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, transition

I use the after pseudo-element to simulate a gradient transition, but my gradients can be different, so I created a class for each one of them and applied them with JS when I needed them. Of course in the general `::after` I specify `transition: opacity 1s;` and in each one of the gradient classes I have a background and `opacity: 1;`. Now I stumbled upon a problem, I need to reverse the transition, but that wasn't so easy, because (since I use JS), I am removing the class, which means that the opacity transition will of course still run, but the background gets deleted immediately. How can I keep the background until the opacity transition ends?

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/5c7xfwLw/

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of what you have so far so we can play with it? Generally in situations like this I have had to use two classes on the element in question; the first initiates the transition and the second is removed when the transition has completed.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5c7xfwLw/1/

Because you are fading out you don't need to remove the background, like this you can do simply the opacity animation.

```
.green:after {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#53FF40, transparent 50%);
}
.fade-after::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about this, but what I am looking for is doing it with only one class